# Выход за пределы списка C#

Tags: c#, матрицы

Есть класс матрицы и метод, который возвращает определитель матрицы - Determinant. По неведомым причинам выходит за пределы двумерного списка. Сидим с друзьями, не можем понять почему так?
Сам код:

```
    public class Matrix
    {
        public List<List<int>> columns = new List<List<int>> { };
       // List<int> row = new List<int> { };


        public void GenerateMatrix(int N) {
            Random random = new Random();
            List<int> row = new List<int> { };
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                row = new List<int> { };
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    row.Add(random.Next(0, 10));
                }
                columns.Add(row);
            }
        }

        public List<List<int>> MatrixReturn() {
            return this.columns;
        }



        public double Determinant(Matrix matrix, int n)
        {
            Matrix mtr = new Matrix();
            mtr.GenerateMatrix(n-1);
            List<int> row = new List<int> { };
            mtr.columns = new List<List<int>> { };


            double det=0;
            if (n != 2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//large matrix
                {
                    mtr.columns = new List<List<int>> { };
                    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < n; i1++)//tiny matrix
                    {
                        row = new List<int> { };
                        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                        {
                            if (i1 != 0 && j != i)
                                row.Add(matrix.columns[i1][j]);
                        }

                        mtr.columns.Add(row);
                    }
                     det += matrix.columns[0][i]*Math.Pow(-1, 1 + i) + Determinant(mtr, n - 1);
                }
                return det;
            }
            else
            {
                return det+ = matrix.columns[0][0] * matrix.columns[1][1] - matrix.columns[0][1] * matrix.columns[1][0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: вы уверены, что надо матрицу создавать `n-1` а в циклах потом считать до `< n` ?

Comment: @teran в циклах код идет по матрице большего размера

Comment: ну и `if (n != 2)` стоит заменить на `if (n > 2)`

Comment: оки, просто в глаза бросилось, а алгебру я уже подзабыл изрядно

Comment: в общем в любом случае, возьмите отладчик и используйте его по назначению, ибо на настоящий момент этот вопрос попадает под _"Просьбы помочь с отладкой"_? что обычно ведет к закрытию.

Comment: интересный, конечно, ООП-стиль :D вроде класс описали, а для чего не ясно. по сути класс вообще не используется никак. декомпозируйте задачу, добавьте методы создающие матрицы из миноров. + и чтобы строки со столбцами в конструкторе создавались, а не в коде каждый раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это безусловное добавление

```
mtr.columns.Add(row);
```

в цикле

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < n; i1++)//tiny matrix
```

явно неправильное - в новую матрицу (минор) при `i1` равном нулю попадает пустой `row`.

Потому и ошибка при последующем вызове `Determinant` - вылезание за границу пустого списка.

Привет друзьям.